# Ist es schlechter Stil einen Satz mit "deshalb" zu beginnen?

Tags: word-usage, style, formality

Ein Freund von mir ist der festen Überzeugung, dass *deshalb* nicht am Satzanfang stehen sollte. Meiner Meinung nach ist das in Ordnung, wenn es sich auf den vorhergehen Satz bezieht.

Kontext ist das Anschreiben in einer Bewerbung, also relativ formal.

Beispiel:

> Ihre Firma legt Wert auf die Weiterbildung ihrer Mitarbeiter und hat eine außergewöhnliche Expertise in diesem Thema. Deshalb bin ich überzeugt, bei Ihnen auf das perfekte Umfeld zu treffen, um meine Ziele zu erreichen.

Comment: Gibt es einen Grund, warum Sie hier einen Nebensatz nicht benutzen? Der Unterschied wära ja nur Komma statt Punkt und "deshalb" statt "Deshalb".

Comment: @Eller, die beiden Hauptsätze durch ein Komma zu trennen macht nicht einen davon zu einem Nebensatz.

Comment: @Eller Im deutschen neigen wir dazu lange Sätze zu schreiben. Aber schön ist das nicht. Persönlich finde ich es sinnvoll, einen Punkt zu setzen, wenn möglich. Außerdem würde ich die Sätze wenn mit einem "und" verbinden oder mit einem anderen Wort den Übergang schaffen, zum Beispiel "weswegen".

Comment: Genau dafür gibt es eigentlich das Semikolon; es zeigt an, dass der Satz noch nicht fertig ist...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Die Zeit** hat vor einigen Jahren mal eine Reihe "Deutsch-Stilkunde" veröffentlicht. Lektion 11 war "Satzanfang". Dort wird der Einstieg mit "Deshalb" (eine *Inversion*) als "einfache und meist unbedenkliche Art, den Satzbeginn zu variieren" bezeichnet.

Hier ein Link zum Artikel: http://www.zeit.de/2012/20/Lektion-11-Saetze-Satzanfang

Ich hätte jedenfalls keine Bedenken, diesen Satz so zu schreiben und würde es langen Schlangensätzen jederzeit vorziehen. *Deshalb* teile ich die feste Überzeugung Deines Freundes nicht.